# Using ODBC & Node.js to insert data

Tags: javascript, node.js, odbc, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

any input would be appreciated.

I'm using an ODBC connection string to connect to my sql database with node.js. I can successfully establish a connection and query the database, but I'm running into trouble when trying to insert data.

The odbc plugin can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc

Here is the example I'm trying to recreate:

```
    var db = require("odbc")()
  , cn = "DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=host;UID=user;PWD=password;DATABASE=dbname"
  ;

//Blocks until the connection is open 
db.openSync(cn);

db.prepare("insert into hits (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)", function (err, stmt) {
  if (err) {
    //could not prepare for some reason 
    console.log(err);
    return db.closeSync();
  }

  //Bind and Execute the statment asynchronously 
  stmt.execute(['something', 42], function (err, result) {
    result.closeSync();

    //Close the connection 
    db.closeSync();
  });
})
```

Here is my code:

```
 var db = require("odbc")()
 , cn = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=host:insert-name.database.windows.net,insert-port;Database=insert-database-name;Uid=insert-uid;Pwd=insert-password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
;
//Blocks until the connection is open


//Blocks until the connection is open
db.openSync(cn);

//Blocks while preparing the statement


db.prepare("INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName, Country, User, Email, PrivacyAgreement, PhoneNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", function (err, stmt) {
  if (err) {
    //could not prepare for some reason
    console.log(err);
    return db.closeSync();
  }
  console.log(stmt);
  //Bind and Execute the statment asynchronously
  stmt.execute(['first','last','country_name', 1, 'emailaccount@gmail.com', 1, '9999999999'], function (err, result) {
    result.closeSync();
    console.log(result);

    //Close the connection
    db.closeSync();
  });
})
```

Note: 'User' and 'PrivacyAgreement' are bit datatype (boolean) and the rest are varchar.

To which, I get the following error:

```
  ODBCStatement { queue: SimpleQueue { fifo: [], executing: true } }
/path/to/file/insert.js:22

 result.closeSync();

    ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'closeSync' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

`result` returned by `stmt.execute` is undefined, must be because `err` is thrown, check for error in `stmt.execute`'s callback.

Also is there specific reason why you are using sync operations over asyn?
If you have no constrains on making async calls, I would recommend trying https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input; I did eventually switch over to asyn (using db.openSync to establish the connection and db.prepareSycn).

The issue was arising from the usage of 'User' as a term - 'User' is reserved in the SQL database I'm connecting to. This issue was solved by add brackets to the term 'User' in the statement string.

The following code works:

let stmt = db.prepareSync('insert into Contact (FirstName, LastName, Country, [User], Email, PrivacyAgreement, PhoneNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')

Thank you all!